# Is there a possibility to get voice from google-text-to-speech and save it in database using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, google-text-to-speech

I'm creating application for vocabulary learning. I want to store my vocabulary + voice/speech(audio file) for every word in database (mongodb, i use mongoose).

My idea is to prepare vocabulary list, my vocabulary list will contains words, every word will be an object that contain 3 properties:
foreign Meaning, native meaning and voice/speech(audio file). Is it possible to store voice/speech in database and use it when i need it?

I already used google-text-to-speech but in documentation i can only read how to save file in my computer.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

// Import other required libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
async function main() {
  // Creates a client
  const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

  // The text to synthesize
  const text = 'Hello, world!';

  // Construct the request
  const request = {
    input: {text: text},
    // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
    voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
    // Select the type of audio encoding
    audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
  };

  // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
  const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
  // Write the binary audio content to a local file
  const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
  await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
  console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
}
```

I want to get voice from text-to-speech and save it in one object with foreign meaning and native meaning in my database.